# Is it possible to create a virtual usb-stick

Tags: esxi

Is it possible to create a virtual usb-stick and plug it from machine to machine to exchange data whithout rebooting?

Comment: How do you mean to plug it if it is virtual?

Comment: via vSphere client? Just like a vdk file for a Disk